# How I can apply groupby two times on pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have pandas data frame with column 'year', 'month' and 'transaction id'. I want to get the transaction count of every month for every year. For ex my data is like:

```
year: {2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2017}
month: {1,  1,   2,   2,   2,    1}
tid: {123,  343, 453, 675, 786, 332}
```

I want to get the output such that for every year I will get the number of transactions per month. For ex for year 2015 I will get the output:

```
month: [1,2]
count: [2,1]
```

I used groupby('year'). but after that how I can get the per month transaction count.

Answer (score 9):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by both columns - `year` and `month` and then aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
year = [2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2017]
month =  [1,  1,   2,   2,   2,    1]
tid = [123,  343, 453, 675, 786, 332]

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':year, 'month':month,'tid':tid})
print (df)
   month  tid  year
0      1  123  2015
1      1  343  2015
2      2  453  2015
3      2  675  2016
4      2  786  2016
5      1  332  2017

df1 = df.groupby(['year','month'])['tid'].size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   year  month  count
0  2015      1      2
1  2015      2      1
2  2016      2      2
3  2017      1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for more complex tasks - suppose you want to group by "year" and a function applied to "tid" - e.g. a bucket categorization

```
def tidBucket(x):
   if x<300:             return "low"
   if (300<=x & x<700):  return "medium"
   if 700<=x:            return "high"
```

Then the above solution would not work. You could solve the problem by first grouping by year, then iterate over the contents of the groupby object with another groupby:

```
gb = df.groupby(by='year') #['tid'].size().reset_index(name='count')
for _,df1 in gb:
    df1.index = df1["tid"]
    df1 = df1.groupby(by=tidBucket)
```

Then aggregate as desired. Alternatively, you could create an additional "bucket" column

```
df["bucket"] = df["tid"].map(tidBucket)
```

and follow the @jezrael 's solution.